# Fluxo de trabalho no R: estratégias para organizar um projeto de análise de dados

Tags: r, workflow, análise-de-dados, versionamento

Tomando como base [esta pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429907/workflow-for-statistical-analysis-and-report-writing), pergunto:

Quais estratégias vocês recomendam para organizar um projeto de análise de dados no `R`? O projeto geralmente envolve as seguintes etapas (não necessariamente nessa ordem):

1. Carregar e "limpar" uma base dados "bruta";
2. Manipular a base de dados para deixá-la nos formatos necessários para visualização e análise;
3. Realizar as análises, construir os gráficos e tabelas;
4. Produzir os relatórios finais;
5. Também, em geral, será necessário criar suas próprias funções para executar os passos anteriores.

Especificando melhor alguns pontos que podem ser abordados (não precisa abordar todos os pontos, são sugestões para orientar as respostas):

Qual a estrutura de pastas e arquivos `.R` utilizar?

É recomendável colocar todas as funções no mesmo arquivo ou em arquivos separados?

Valeria a pena criar um pacote para essas funções, ao invés de ficar dando `source`?

Que funções, pacotes etc são recomendados para gerenciar esse processo? Controle de versão é recomendável em um projeto deste tipo?

Com relação aos scripts de execução da análise, seria melhor colocar toda análise em um único script ou separar um script por atividade (criar base dados, limpar base dados etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu tenho trabalho em projetos que envolvem a integração de diversas fontes de dados, transformação dos dados e geração de relatórios. Os scripts são principalmente em R, mas às vezes recorro a outras linguagens.

Tenho criado os seguintes diretórios: `report/`, `script/`, `lib/`, `data/`, `raw-data/` e `doc/`. O código-fonte fica em `script/` e `lib/`, os dados em `data/` e `raw-data/` e os relatórios em `report/`. A ideia geral é criar pequenos scripts R que transformam os dados sucessivamente até chegar a dados formatados para serem usados em relatórios.

Em `raw-data/` guardo dados que foram criados ou obtidos manualmente, geralmente em arquivos `.csv` ou similares. Os scripts leem dados de `raw-data` (ou de `data/`), possivelmente realizam algumas transformações (filtro, agrupamento etc.) e criam arquivos em `data/`, geralmente usando a função `saveRDS`, de forma que possam ser lidos rapidamente usando a função `readRDS`. Cada script é pequeno e geralmente grava apenas um arquivo `rds` contendo um data frame. Se existirem funções usadas em mais de um script, elas ficam em arquivos na pasta `lib/` e são carregados usando a função `source` (com a opção `chdir=TRUE`). Os scripts usam extensivamente o pacote [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).

Na pasta `doc/` eu procuro manter dois diagramas atualizados: um com os data frames e suas colunas e outro que descreve o pipeline de transformação de dados (um diagrama com scripts e arquivos de dados, indicando para cada script, quais arquivos ele lê e quais ele escreve). A vantagem de documentar o pipeline é que, quando algum arquivo muda (por exemplo, por causa da chegada de dados mais atuais), é fácil determinar quais scripts precisam ser executados e em que ordem para atualizar os dados usados nos relatórios finais. Uso o [yEd](http://yworks.com/yed) para criar os diagramas.

[image: Documentação do pipeline]

Alguns dos scripts em `script/` geram relatórios. Eles são escritos para serem compilados com o [knitr::spin](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-spin.R) e criam arquivos HTML em `report/`, frequentemente contendo gráficos gerados com o [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/).

O projeto é mantido sob controle de versão usando o [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/). Eu evito manter no controle de versão os arquivos em `data/`, já que eles podem ser grandes e muitos deles podem ser gerados a partir dos scripts e dos dados em `raw-data/`. A exceção é para arquivos de dados que são derivados de bancos de dados externos. Nesse caso eu coloco o arquivo em controle de versão para garantir que pessoas sem acesso ao banco de dados possam executar o projeto.

Um exemplo de projeto que usa esse fluxo de trabalho pode ser encontrado em https://github.com/rodrigorgs/arch-violations-bugs

A vantagem de usar vários scripts especializados é que, se alguma fonte de dados é atualizada ou se uma nova coluna precisa ser calculada em um data frame, só é preciso executar novamente os scripts que lidam com aquele data frame. Isso é especialmente importante quando o projeto envolve transformações de dados lentas ou acesso a fontes de dados externas como a web e sistemas de gerenciamento de bancos de dados.

Comment: A documentação do pipeline e até a execução dos scripts na ordem certa é um processo que pode ser automatizado. Não encontrei nenhuma solução pronta para isso, mas se alguém tiver interesse em desenvolver uma, vamos conversar.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, bem mais interessante inclusive que aquelas do SOEN!

Comment: Você não costuma compilar as funções em um pacote? Isso é algo que estou cada vez mais achando que vale a pena, mesmo quando são poucas funções!

Comment: Nunca parei pra estudar empacotamento em R, mas um dia tenho que parar pra olhar. Você usa https://github.com/hadley/devtools ?

Comment: Uso, mas não para tudo - uso muito o Roxygen2 também, é uma mão na roda para documentar as funções!