# Qual a melhor forma de selecionar e organizar dados do R?

Tags: r, organização-de-projeto

Tenho um projeto que consiste em realizar regressões não lineares para vários conjuntos de dados de origens diferentes. Depois de realizar todas estas operações, costumo salvar os resultados em arquivos .txt, para não precisar ficar voltando ao mesmo workspace o tempo todo.

O problema é que estou com vários arquivos diferentes, e navegar dentro das pastas esta se tornando cada vez mais confuso. Por isso, pergunto:

Alguém tem sugestão de organização melhor do que que utilizo no momento?

Comment: Este artigo pode ajudar: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000424. Mas sua pergunta é muito ampla. Você precisa organizar só os resultados ou também os dados? Quais informações dos resultados você precisa? Essas informações são para você ou serão compartilhadas? As informações serão usadas no R ou serão lidas em outros programas? A melhor forma de organização é uma questão pessoal e depende da situação.

Comment: @VictorSartor, quem sabe [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8537/43953) e sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8588/43953) possam lhe ajudar.